# Decrementing an iterator until the .begin() of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I need to read a vector backward from a certain position of an iterator, and put up to n1 values in the dictionnary array.

I though about making a loop and decrementing the iterator, but for some reasons I'm stuck in an infinite loop.

I think there's an issue in the while condition?

```
//I read all the vSignal vector
while (vSignalIt != vSignal.end()) {

    i = 0;
    vSignalIt2 = vSignalIt;

    //Filling the dictionnary array
    if (vSignalIt != vSignal.begin()) {
        do 
        {
            dictionnary[i] = *vSignalIt2;
            vSignalIt2--;
            i++;
        } while (vSignalIt2 != vSignal.begin() || i < (uint8_t)n1);
    }

    //Do something with the value of dictionnary and increase vSignalIt to advance forward in the vSignal vector

}
```

Comment: why not use a [`reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) which is designed for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: In case you really want to do this, the problem may inside `||` or `i < (uint8_t)n1`

Comment: I'll edit the question to provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the '||' to '&&'

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong conditional checker for your statement. Currently it is:

```
while (vSignalIt2 != vSignal.begin() || i < (uint8_t)n1);
```

But it should be:

```
while (vSignalIt2 != vSignal.begin() && i < (uint8_t)n1); //<-- && means 'and'
```

Also, as a recommendation, you should probably use a [`reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) because it is built for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider standard algorithms instead:

```
auto vSignalIt = vSignal.rbegin(); // or some other reverse iterator
auto n = std::min(n1, std::distance(vSignalIt, vSignal.rend());
std::copy_n(vSignalIt, n, std::back_inserter(dictionary));
```

Comment: Could you clarify what this is doing?

Comment: At first you need a reverse iterator to the starting point (I just used `.rbegin()` for examples sake, you have to use the appropriate algorithm for your case). Then you calculate the number of items to be copied: it is `n1` but no more than you have elements in `vSignal` left (the `std::distance`-part). Then you copy `n` elements from `vSignal` starting at `vSignalIt` backwards (because its a reverse iterator) and insert it into `dictionary`.